# Why do parentheses cause object to become unbound?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When I surround a new object invocation with parens and call a method on it immediately Node (or just v8 in general) will throw a "TypeError: this.getName is not a function" error. If I don't wrap it in parens no then no error will get thrown and `this` is properly bound.

```
function Greeter(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Greeter.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

Greeter.prototype.helloWorld = function() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.getName()}`);
}

// Throws, this in any class methods are bound to the global
(new Greeter('Olive')).helloWorld();
// Doesn't throw, this is bound to the object as expected
new Greeter('Olive').helloWorld();
```

What do the parens get interpreted as here, and why is 'helloWorld' unbound?

Comment: I feel like this used to work.... am I not seeing something obvious?

Comment: You're relying on (ASI) automatic semicolon insertion to interpret what you actually meant. It sees a function expression followed by `(...)` so it is invoking your function at the set step

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are depending on automatic semi-colon insertion and it isn't working the way you expect.

This:

> ```
> Greeter.prototype.helloWorld = function() {
>   console.log(`Hello ${this.getName()}`);
> }
>
> // Throws, this in any class methods are bound to the global
> (new Greeter('Olive')).helloWorld();
> ```

is equivalent to:

```
let mygreeter = new Greeter('Olive');

let result_of_call = (function() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.getName()}`);
}(mygreeter));

Greeter.prototype.helloWorld = result_of_call.helloWorld();
```

You need to put a semi-colon after the previous expression to prevent the `(...)` being interpreted as "Call this function as an IIFE with arguments"

```
Greeter.prototype.helloWorld = function() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.getName()}`);
};

(new Greeter('Olive')).helloWorld();
```

Comment: What a JavaScript wizard.

Comment: Oh this is what happens when I start a project with my linter turned off *facepalm*

Comment: This is awesome, I programmed with javascript for years and I took some time to understand the problem and your answer too. Now it looks almost obvious, if we don't rely on semicolons then it's like that code is on a single line, and that's exactly an IIFE. Just a question, why don't we need parenthesis around the function too?

Comment: @CristianTraìna — Being on the right hand side of an `=` puts it in expression context.

Comment: @Quentin I just did some test and I discovered that the equals makes the magic as well. Where did you learn about expression context?

Comment: @CristianTraìna — Haven't a clue. It was a very long time ago.

Comment: @CristianTraìna If you read the ES5 spec, you'll see that expressions arise all the time, it is where you are for the majority of the code; e.g. [the grouping operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6), [unary operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4) and basically everything else you actually "do". ASI basically works by asking "is this a valid expression?" and if not, tries to insert a semicolon. This means ASI can also behave differently if a new feature results in a new valid expression